# How to install pyhook for python 3.4?

Tags: python, module, installation, python-3.4, pyhook

How do I install pyhook for python 3.4? I can find the files for 2.7, but not 3.4.
Does anyone have the download link to get pyhook for python 3.4? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download compiled version from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

After this run `pip install pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score -2):

It looks like it exists in PyPi, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook/1.5.1.

Try installing via:

```
pip install pyhook
```

If it complains that it could not find a version that satisfies requirements, then the developer has probably not released a version compatible with Python 3.x.

In such a case, if the library is simple/small enough, you may be able to modify the source to be Python 3.x compatible.